# Algorithm: optimizing 'balancing brackets'

Tags: javascript, algorithm

***I have been posed the following question...***

*Given a N different open and close braces in a string "( { [ } ] )", check whether the string has matching braces. Return true if the braces match, false otherwise.*

***Here is the answer I came up with...***

```
function braceeql(braces){
  var leftpar = 0; 
  var rightpar = 0; 
  var leftbrace = 0;
  var rightbrace = 0;
  var leftcurl = 0;
  var rightcurl = 0;

  for(var index = 0; index < braces.length; index++){
    if(braces[index] == ')'){
      leftpar += 1;
    }else if(braces[index] == '('){
      rightpar += 1;
    }else if(braces[index] == '['){
      leftbrace += 1;
    }else if(braces[index] == ']'){
      rightbrace += 1;
    }else if(braces[index] == '{'){
      leftcurl += 1;
    }else if(braces[index] == '}'){
      rightcurl += 1;
    }
  }
  if(leftcurl == rightcurl && leftbrace == rightbrace && leftpar == rightpar){
    console.log(true)
  }else{
    console.log(false)
  }
}
```

This is really meaty piece of code, but it sure as heck works. I am seeing  differing opinions about how others attacked this problem, but am left wondering ***is there a better/cleaner way of solving this algorithm without compromising the big O?***

I am very open to suggestions and other ways of looking at this problem.

Comment: use only a single variable `brace`, `curl` and `par` and increment decrement it. In the end just check if all are `==` to `0`.

Comment: What is the definition for "matching braces"? To me, `[()]` is okay, `[(])` is not. Your code checks for the latter; for the former, you would need a stack.

Comment: Perhaps you want http://codereview.stackexchange.com if you're just looking for ways to improve your working code.

Comment: @jfriend00: You're missing an `x` in eXchange. However, the current code isn't correct (if `[(])` is invalid), and therefore might be off-topic on CR.

Comment: @Zeta - The OP says the code works, so that's what I was going by.

Comment: Instead of writing every single bracket why not put them into an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, your solution doesn't seem to cover cases like )(][ or ({)} (I'm not sure you were asked to do it, but this toy problem as I know it requests it)

This is a solution for this toy problem I made over a year ago, but it seems faster(it will stop earlier if it doesnt match, has less ifs and elses) and repeats less code, but I'm not sure about cleaner, as ifs and elses are easier to understand from a novice point of view

```
var braceeql = function(braces){
  var stack = {};
  var size = 0;
  var beginners = ['(', '[', '{'];
  var enders = [')', ']', '}'];
  for(var i = 0; i < braces.length; i++){
    if( beginners.indexOf(braces[i]) !== -1 ){
      stack[size] = braces[i];
      size++;
    } else if( enders.indexOf(braces[i]) !== -1 ){
      if(size === 0) { return false; }
      var index = enders.indexOf(braces[i]);
      if(stack[size-1] === beginners[index] ){
        size --;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  return size === 0;
};
```

Answer (score 11):

## Using Stack

The following solution has a time complexity of ***O(n)***

```js
function isBalanced(str) {
  const stack = [];
  const map = {
    '(': ')',
    '[': ']',
    '{': '}',
  };
  const closing = Object.values(map);

  for (let char of str) {
    if (map[char]) {
      stack.push(char);
    } else if (closing.includes(char) && char !== map[stack.pop()]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return !stack.length;
}

console.log(isBalanced('{[())}')); // false 
console.log(isBalanced('{[()]}')); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a stretch, but why not use a well defined stack. It's good practice.

```
//stack
class STACK 
{
  //initialize
  constructor()
  {
    this.arr = [];
  }
  //add to stack
  add(data)
  {
    this.arr.push(data);
  }
  //remote from stack
  remove()
  {
    return this.arr.pop();
  }
  //print the stack
  print()
  {
    console.log('-----');
    for(let i = this.arr.length-1; i >=0; i--)
      console.log('|',this.arr[i],'|');
    console.log('-----');
  }
  //peek last element
  peek()
  {
    return this.arr[this.arr.length-1];
  }
  //check if empty
  empty()
  {
    if(this.arr.length===0)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
}

//Use stack to check for balanced paranthesis
const balanceParantheses = (str)=>{
  obj = new STACK();
  for(let char of str)
  {
    if(char==='[' || char==='{' || char ==='(')
      obj.add(char);
    else {
      switch(char)
      {
        case(']'):
          if(obj.empty())
            return false;
          else if(obj.peek()!=='[') {
            return false
          } else obj.remove();
          break;
        case(')'):
          if(obj.empty())
            return false;
          else if(obj.peek()!=='(') {
            return false
          } else obj.remove();
          break;
        case('}'):
          if(obj.empty())
            return false;
          else if(obj.peek()!=='{') {
            return false
          } else obj.remove();
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(balanceParantheses("[()]{}{[()()]()}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter variable (Source: Solution #3, Page 496, [Fundamentals of Computer Programming with C#](https://www.introprogramming.info/)):

```js
let openers = {
    curly: '{',
    square: '[',
    paren: '('
  };

  let closers = {
    curly: '}',
    square: ']',
    paren: ')'
  };

  function isBalanced(str) {
    let counter = 0;

    for (let char of str) {
      if (char === openers.curly || char === openers.square || char === openers.paren)
        counter++;

      if (char === closers.curly || char === closers.square || char === closers.paren)
        counter--;

      if (counter < 0) 
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
  
  console.log(isBalanced("[]"));
  console.log(isBalanced("]][[[][][][]]["));
  console.log(isBalanced("[][[[[][][[[]]]]]]"));
  console.log(isBalanced("]["));
  console.log(isBalanced("[[[]]]][[]"));
  console.log(isBalanced("[]][[]]][[[[][]]"));
  console.log(isBalanced("[[]][[][]]"));
  console.log(isBalanced("[[]]"));
  console.log(isBalanced("]][]][[]][[["));
  console.log(isBalanced("][]][][["));
  console.log(isBalanced("][]["));
  console.log(isBalanced("[[]]][][][[]]["));
  console.log(isBalanced(""));
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to pay any attention to which brace is involved, e.g., if you change the first example to `"[}"` it will return `true`, which doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution via Stack structure.

```
const input = '{a[b{c(d)e}f]g}';

function isBalanced(str) {
  let stack = [];
  let closeMap = new Map([
    [']', '['], 
    ['}', '{'], 
    [')', '(']
  ]);
  let openSet = new Set(closeMap.values());

  for (let ch of str) {
    if(closeMap.has(ch) && 
      (!stack.length || stack.pop() != closeMap.get(ch)))
        return false;            
    else if(openSet.has(ch)) 
      stack.push(ch);
    else continue;
  }

  return (!stack.length)
};

console.log('result is: ' + isBalanced(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isBalanced(str = "") {
    if (typeof str !== "string" || str.trim().length === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    str = str.replace(/[^{}()\[\]]/g, "");
    if (typeof str !== "string" || str.trim().length === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    while (str.length > 0) {
        let perviousLenght = str.length;
        str = str.replace(/\(\)/g, "");
        str = str.replace(/{}/g, "");
        str = str.replace(/["'\[]]/g, "");
        if (str.length === perviousLenght) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
console.log("Good Values ==>");
console.log(isBalanced("[()]"));
console.log(isBalanced("(function(){return [new Bears()]}());"));
console.log(isBalanced("var a = function(){return 'b';}"));
console.log(isBalanced("//Complex object;\n a = [{a:1,b:2,c:[ new Car( 1, 'black' ) ]}]"));
console.log("Bad Values ==>");
console.log(isBalanced("{"));
console.log(isBalanced("{]"));
console.log(isBalanced("{}("));
console.log(isBalanced("({)()()[][][}]"));
console.log(isBalanced("(function(){return [new Bears()}())];"));
console.log(isBalanced("var a = [function(){return 'b';]}"));
console.log(isBalanced("/*Comment: a = [} is bad */var a = function({)return 'b';}"));
console.log(isBalanced("/*[[[ */ function(){return {b:(function(x){ return x+1; })'c')}} /*_)(([}*/"));
console.log(isBalanced("//Complex object;\n a = [{a:1,b:2,c:[ new Car( 1, 'black' ) ]]"));
```

Comment: The best questions have some kind of description along with any code they paste. I think this question in particular would warrant some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution in JavaScript

### Time complexity O(n)

```js
/**
 * @param {string} s
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var checkParanthesis = function(s) {
    if(typeof s !== "string" || s.length % 2 !== 0) return false;
    let i = 0;
    let arr = [];
    while(i<s.length) {
        if(s[i]=== "{" || s[i]=== "(" || s[i]=== "[") {
           arr.push(s[i]);
        } else if(s[i] === "}" && arr[arr.length-1] === "{") {
            arr.pop()
        } else if(s[i] === ")" && arr[arr.length-1] === "(") {
            arr.pop()
        } else if(s[i] === "]" && arr[arr.length-1] === "[") {
            arr.pop()
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        i++
    }
    return arr.length === 0;
};
let str = "{([])}";
console.log(checkParanthesis(str))
```

Answer (score -1):

This was my take on the problem:

```
const isBalance = str => {
  const result = !str.split('').reduce((accum, current) => {
    if (accum < 0) return accum
    else {
      if (current === '(') return accum+= 1
      if (current === ')') return accum-= 1
      if (current === '[') return accum+= 2
      if (current === ']') return accum-= 2
      if (current === '{') return accum+= 3
      if (current === '}') return accum-= 3    
    }

  }, 0)

  return result
}
```

This solution will give you O(n).
One thing that could improve this solution is if we reach `accum < 0` (meaning that there is a closed brace that doesn't match anywhere), immediately you can stop iterating.

Plus it's much easier to read the code

Comment: This returns `true` for `"((]"`; simply adding values for specific brace types is insufficient--that doesn't allow for any context, e.g., which brace.