# Return the balanced brackets if returning false

Tags: javascript

I’m currently working on a project that basically checks if the given string of brackets is balanced or not e.g:
{()} returns true
{(}) returns false
I already have this but is there a way to return the actual string if it returns false? e.g.
{() returns {()}? If you can point me to a website or something that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm: optimizing 'balancing brackets'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868737/algorithm-optimizing-balancing-brackets)

Comment: There is a very long blog post worth a read about this problem http://raganwald.com/2019/02/14/i-love-programming-and-programmers.html if you'd like to take a long view on the theory.

Comment: I already solved how to return true or false it's just I want to output the actual bracket string

Comment: Use a utility function; `const trueOrString = (string) => mySolvingFunction(string) ? true : string;`
it's a side effect, you probably don't want to make the original function return the string, break it up functional style.

Comment: you might want to clarify the question, the problem isn't the balancing brackets; that is distracting from the real question: _how do I the value from a true/false function if the function returns false_

Comment: This duplicate doesn't even match my requirements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the easiest option would be to re-create the expected output string of matched opening and closing brackets as follows:

1) If the input string has more open brackets than closing brackets:
   Trim the string to just use the opening brackets, then append on the matching closing 
   brackets.

2) If the input string has more closing brackets than opening:
   Trim off the opening brackets at the start and working backwards pre-pend the matching 
   opening brackets.

This algorithm would be simple and work assuming you are not expecting cases like
{(}(} where the opening and closing brackets are not grouped in order.

If you needed to handle these sorts of cases a similar approach which is recursive could be applied to correct the brackets starting with indices at the extreme left and right ends work inwards to find the matching bracket and recurse, if no matching bracket assume one should exist at the exremity (left or right depending on which bracket wasn't found).

Comment: Yeah this could work, but I wouldn't want to trim but to add... like if I had {() I don't want to trim off { but instead to add } to it so it would {()} not ()

Comment: The case your suggested would be covered by the above approach. If you start with {() you have 2 opening and 1 closing. Remove the closing bracket so you just have {( Then for each of those opening brackets append the matching close bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the function working try something functional like the following:

```
const myFancySolution = (string) => { /* amazing solution */ }

// come up with a better name than this ⬇️
const valueOrTrue = (fn) => (val) => fn(val) ? true : val

const mySolutionOrSelf = valueOrTrue(myFancySolution)
```

Comment: so if myFancySolution the function I use to get the true or false?? and fn is also my function???

Comment: You are essentially using a function to create a new entry point to your solution: the one that returns true or false, `valueOrTrue` returns a function that applies your function to its function so:
`valueOrTrue((a) => a === 1)(2)` will return 2

Comment: Or if you had a function `const alwaysFalse  = ()  => false` and you create a function `const alwaysValue = valueOrTrue(alwaysFalse)` you can invoke it like `alwaysValue('{}') // => '{}'`