# How to check for valid braces in javascript, programming problem?

Tags: javascript

have been struggling for the last couple of days with the following problem from codewars:

Write a function that takes a string of braces, and determines if the order of the braces is valid. It should return  `true`  if the string is valid, and  `false`  if it's invalid.

All input strings will be nonempty, and will only consist of parentheses, brackets and curly braces:  `()[]{}` .

#### What is considered Valid?

A string of braces is considered valid if all braces are matched with the correct brace.

### Examples

```
"(){}[]"   =>  True
"([{}])"   =>  True
"(}"       =>  False
"[(])"     =>  False
"[({})](]" =>  False
```

So I'm really stuck with the code for this one, and this is what I have up to this point:

```
function validBraces(braces){
    let opening = [ '(', '[', '{']
    let closing = [ ')', ']', '}']
    let count = 0
    const left = []
    const right = []

    // I generate left and right arrays, left w/the opening braces from the input, right w/ the closing
    for (let i = 0; i < braces.length; i++) {
        if (opening.includes(braces[i])) {
            left.push(braces[i])
        } else if (closing.includes(braces[i])) {
            right.push(braces[i])
        }
    }
    if (braces.length % 2 !== 0) {
        return false
    }
    // I know there's no point in doing this but at one point I thought I was finishing the program and thought I would 'optimize it' to exit early, probably this is dumb haha.
    if (left.length !== right.length) {
        return false
    }
    // The juicy (not juicy) part where I check if the braces make sense
    for (let i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
    // If the list are made up of braces like  ()[]{} add one to counter
        if (opening.indexOf(left[i]) === closing.indexOf(right[i])) {
            count += 1
        } else // If left and right are mirrored add one to the counter
            if (opening.indexOf(left[i]) === closing.indexOf(right.reverse()[i])) {
                count += 1
            }
}
    //If the counter makes sense return true
    if (count === braces.length / 2) {
        return true
    } else { return false}
}


console.log(validBraces( "()" )) //true
console.log(validBraces("([])")) //true
console.log(validBraces( "[(])" )) //false
console.log(validBraces( "[(})" )) //false
console.log(validBraces( "[([[]])]" )) //true
```

Some comments: I know I'm still not checking for this example ([])() but I thought of breaking this up into two smaller checks in some way.

Thank you if you read up to this point. I would appreciate guidance in some way, though I don't want the problem solved for me. I'm probably overcomplicating this in some way since its a 6kyu problem, if so a tip on how to approach it more cleverly would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance! :pray: :pray:

Comment: You might be over-thinking it. It boils down to pushing opening braces and popping when see a closing brace, and seeing if they match up.

Comment: Not really sure if this is allowed or not but the last video I made on my youtube channel I solve exactly this problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQl3YrpHbkI&t=88s

Comment: FWIW, not including several lines of test values, is clocking in at around 20 LOC. Using a single stack; no need for multiple AFAICT. I'd guess it could get dropped down to about half-ish of that and stay readable. You're on (roughly) the right track--simplify, re-frame the problem to its essence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Algorithm: optimizing 'balancing brackets'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868737/algorithm-optimizing-balancing-brackets)

Comment: Folks, **please** keep in mind the OP is *explicitly* trying to solve this for themselves. Pointing at answers or providing solutions, particularly overly-complex ones, is not what they're asking for.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks man! Exactly the kind of hint I was hoping for, I'll try to do what you suggested.

Comment: @santsleo Great--when you complete it, post your answer (as an answer). It's a fun little problem, with a number of approaches. When I approach novel problems I almost always err on the side of simplicity first then look for ways to optimize or clean it up. (Working && readable) > clever. Have fun!

Comment: @DaveNewton what do you think of my final solution?

Comment: Valid Parentheses In Javascript. Simple and accepted solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822125/check-if-quotes-and-parentheses-are-balanced/74582824#74582824

Answer (score 4):

Hell yeah!! I'm very happy to finally reach to the solution myself using some of the hints given to me here:

```js
function validBraces(braces){
    let opening = [ '(', '[', '{']
    let closing = [ ')', ']', '}']
    let arr = []
    //console.log(closing.indexOf(braces[")"]) === opening.indexOf(arr[")"]))
    for (let i = 0; i < braces.length; i++) {
        if (opening.includes(braces[i])) {
            arr.push(braces[i])
        } else
        if (closing.indexOf(braces[i]) === opening.indexOf(arr[arr.length - 1])) {
            arr.pop()
        } else return false
    } return arr.length === 0;
}
```

I was clearly overthinking it in the first place haha. Thanks for everyone that helped!

Comment: Glad you got it working :) The only real "issue" (not much of an issue given the constraints) is that this does a lot of "hidden" iteration (`includes` and multiple `indexOf`). That's why you'll see a lot of solutions using an object or `Map`. But, as I've learned recently, using an object/map may incur performance penalties on small collections, so I'd guess this is actually *faster* than map-based solutions, although I haven't tested.

Comment: Bottom line--good work, good enthusiasm, good you took the time to puzzle it out and post an answer. I'd upvote twice if I could.

Comment: Don't forget that you can mark your answer as the accepted answer! Very nice implementation!

Answer (score 2):

```js
var validBraces = (s) => {
    let objO  = {'(': 0, '[': 1, '{': 2};
    let objC  = {')': 0, ']': 1, '}': 2};
    let stack = [];

    for (let i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
        if (objO.hasOwnProperty(s[i])) {
            if (stack.length === 0 || stack[stack.length-1].idx!==objO[s[i]])
                stack.push({idx: objO[s[i]], count: 1});
            else
                stack[stack.length-1].count++;
        }
        else if (objC.hasOwnProperty(s[i])) {
            if (stack.length === 0 || stack[stack.length-1].idx!==objC[s[i]])
                return false;
            else {
                stack[stack.length-1].count--;
                if (stack[stack.length-1].count===0)
                    stack.pop();
            }
        }
    }
    return stack.length === 0;
};

console.log(validBraces("(){}[]"));
console.log(validBraces("([{}])"));
console.log(validBraces("(})"));
console.log(validBraces("[(])"));
console.log(validBraces("[({})](]"));
```

Comment: Seems somewhat over-engineered.

Answer (score 2):

As Dave suggested, using a stack, I've wrote the code for it:

```
var leftBraces="([{";
var rightBraces=")]}";

function checkBraces(braces) {
  var ok=true;
  var stack=[];
  for(var i=0; i<braces.length && ok; i++) {
    var brace=braces[i];
    if(leftBraces.includes(brace)) stack.push(brace);
    else {
      var leftBrace=stack.pop();
      if(leftBrace==undefined) ok=false;
      else if(leftBraces.indexOf(leftBrace)!=rightBraces.indexOf(brace)) ok=false;
    }
  }
  if(stack.length) ok=false;
  return ok;
}
```

Code assumes only braces (no spaces or other characters).
I'm using `string.indexOf()` that matches for `leftBraces` and `rightBraces`.
Also, within the `for` loop, notice the termination part (2nd): `i<braces.length && ok` - doesn't "have to" use the iterator and, if I'm not mistaken, can even be empty...

Comment: So, could you up-vote good answers and select the best?
Hopefully - mine... :)

Comment: Valid Parentheses In Javascript. Simple and accepted solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822125/check-if-quotes-and-parentheses-are-balanced/74582824#74582824

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified solution:

```
let isMatchingBraces = function(str) {
    let stack = [];
    let symbol = {
        '(': ')',
        '[': ']',
        '{': '}'
    };
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
        // If character is an opening brace add it to a stack
        if (str[i] === '(' || str[i] === '{' || str[i] === '[') {
            stack.push(str[i]);
        }
        //  If that character is a closing brace, pop from the stack, which will also reduce the length of the stack each time a closing bracket is encountered.
        else {
            let last = stack.pop();
            //If the popped element from the stack, which is the last opening brace doesn’t match the corresponding closing brace in the symbol, then return false
            if (str[i] !== symbol[last]) {
                return false
            };
        }
    }
    // After checking all the brackets of the str, at the end, the stack is not 
    // empty then fail
    if (stack.length !== 0) {
        return false
    };
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Valid Parentheses In Javascript. Simple and accepted solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822125/check-if-quotes-and-parentheses-are-balanced/74582824#74582824

Answer (score 1):

```
function validBraces(braces){
    let par =0;
    let bra =0;
    let cur =0;
    for(let i =0; i<braces.length; i++){
        if(braces[i]==="("){
            par++;
        }
        if(braces[i]===")"){
            par--;
        }
        if(braces[i]==="["){
            bra++;
        }
        if(braces[i]==="]"){
            bra--;
        }
        if(braces[i]==="{"){
            cur++;
        }
        if(braces[i]==="}"){
            cur--;
        }
    }

    if(par<0 || bra<0 || cur<0){
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
};
```

Comment: Your code would be better if you used a `switch` statement instead of all of those `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
var isValid = function (s) {
  let charMap = new Map();

  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    charMap.set(s[i], i);
  }

  return Boolean(
    charMap.get("(") < charMap.get(")") &&
    charMap.get("(") % 2 != charMap.get(")") % 2 &&
    charMap.get("{") < charMap.get("}") &&
    charMap.get("{") % 2 != charMap.get("}") % 2 &&
    charMap.get("[") < charMap.get("]") &&
    charMap.get("[") % 2 != charMap.get("]") % 2
  );
};
```

Explanation:

1. In order to achieve a quick and short solution, I have identified the common pattern of validity for opening/closing braces.
2. The common pattern for opening and closing braces' validity is that if say the opening(closing) stands at the even index in the string, the other one should be odd and vice versa. Example {}, {[]}, {()[]}, {[()]}.
3. Because we want to avoid a double loop for performance reasons, we are using a Hash Table via Map() to store the character and the index.
4. An alternative for getting the character's index would be using Array's find or another method, but that would end up in a second loop over the values which we want to avoid.
5. Finally, once the indexes of and the characters are stored in the charMap, we check whether or not the stored closing/opening characters' standing (odd/even) in the string is not equal, e.g. if '(' is odd the ')' should be even and vice versa.
6. We check this via the remainder (%) operator, i.e. a number's remainder of 2 is 0 if even.
7. Additionally, we need to check whether the order of braces is correct, e.g. if '(' is before '}';
8. The Boolean() function coerces the comparisons in the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: @GiorgioTempesta, thank you. Adding the explanation.